# str_contains() gives HTTP ERROR 500 | Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get list of all those files whose extension is jpeg,jpg or png and title contains '100x100' text.

I can easily get the list of files filtering by their extension, that's working fine but when I add a condition into it `&& str_contains($value,'100x100')` then page is not working and gives `HTTP ERROR 500`

function:

```
function scan_files(){
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $folder = $upload_dir['basedir'];
    $files = list_files( $folder );
    
   foreach($files as $value){
    if(pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=='jpeg'||pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=='jpg'||pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=='png' && str_contains($value,'100x100')){

        $filtered_files[] = $value;
            }
    
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($filtered_files);
    }
```

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**

According @luk2302 's comment I have corrected the `)` issue and page is working fine but values are not getting filtered, also according to @CBroe 's comment, I am using php7 so I replaced `str_contains` with `strpos` but still it's not giving expected results.

New Code:

```
function scan_files(){
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $folder = $upload_dir['basedir'];
    $files = list_files( $folder );
    
   foreach($files as $value){
    if(pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=='jpeg'||pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=='jpg'||pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=='png' && strpos($value,'100x100')!==false){

        $filtered_files[] = $value;
            }
    
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($filtered_files);
    }
```

Comment: Missing at least a `)`.

Comment: Whats the PHP version used?

Comment: Also, this function is available from PHP 8.0 on only.

Comment: Thank you for quick answers, according @luk2302 's comment I have corrected the `)` issue and page is working fine but values are not getting filtered, also according to @CBroe 's comment, I am using php7 so I replaced `str_contains` with `strpos` but still it's not giving expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
if(pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=='jpeg'||pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=='jpg'||pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=='png' && strpos($value,'100x100')!==false){
```

To:

```
if((pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=='jpeg'||pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=='jpg'||pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=='png') && strpos($value,'100x100')!==false){
```

Notice the extra parentheses around your pathinfo statements. You want to check if any of the extensions are true AND the path contains your key value. Your original code would only filter on filename if the extension was png.